# Evaluate $\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{x+y}}dydx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

How to show
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{x+y}}d\sigma=-\frac{128 a}{9}+\frac{16}{3} \sqrt{2 a} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\right)+\frac{8}{3} \sqrt{2} \log (2)$$
Where $a=\sqrt{2}-1$? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that $u=\sqrt{x+y}$ works

Comment: Integration by parts works, even the indefinite Integral exists. I guess one also find the integral in Gradsteyn

Comment: @Fengshan Xiong: I understand, I was just playing with your integral in Mathematica.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1777755  and  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1780801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can exploit a symmetry and split the integral in half along the line $y=x$ then use the following modified polar coordinates:

$$x = s^{\frac{2}{3}}\cos\theta \hspace{10 pt} y = s^{\frac{2}{3}}\sin\theta$$

$$\implies 2\cdot \frac{2}{3}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sec^{\frac{3}{2}}\theta} \frac{\log\left(s^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}}dsd\theta = \frac{16}{9}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sec^{\frac{3}{2}}\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}}\left(\frac{3}{2}\log(\sec\theta)-1\right)d\theta$$

then let $x=\tan\theta$

$$ \implies \frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx - \frac{16}{9}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$$

The integral on the right evaluates to $\frac{32}{9}(\sqrt{2}-1) \equiv \frac{32}{9}a$. The integral on the left becomes

$$ = \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{2}\log 2 - \frac{16}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{x\sqrt{1+x}}{1+x^2}dx$$

We have one and a half of the three terms the user posted, but this last integral is tricky and isn't yielding to a variety of methods. I will try to finish later, but in the meantime if anyone has any clever suggestions for this last integral I will be happy try it.

Comment: For the last integral, you can just substitute $u=\sqrt{1+x}$, then use partial fractions.

Comment: @Prasiortle that doesn't work nicely as the denominator $u^4-2u^2+2$ is not factorable over $\mathbb{R}$ as far as I can tell. And I would prefer to avoid complex logs, they are not elegant.

Comment: If you only want to work over $\mathbb{R}$ then I don't think you can solve this integral analytically, since there appears to be no way to express the antiderivative of $\frac{x\sqrt{1+x}}{1+x^2}$ without using complex numbers.

Comment: @Prasiortle we don't need to compute the antiderivative. We have a definite integral. Not to mention just because wolfram doesn't spit out an answer without complex numbers does not mean it cannot be simplified to not have them. But again, this is a definite integral, no antiderivative necessary.

Comment: Correct, but that doesn't help. You've already said complex methods are out, and there's no trick like DUTIS that can be used here (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Prasiortle then please wait for someone to come by with a clever method, instead of saying you don't know one. There are tons of methods that you and I are unfamiliar with involving complicated series or special functions and the like, so your comments haven't told me anything we don't already know.